# Zip pandas dataframes into a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

df_A

```
   country_codes
0              4
1              8
2             12
3             16
4             24
```

and df_B

```
   continent_codes
0                4
1                3
2                5
3                6
4                5
```

Both dataframes have same length, but no common column. I want to concatenate the two but since not all values are common, I get lots of NaNs. How do I concatenate or zip them up into a combined dataframe?

-- EDIT desired output is this:

```
   country_codes   continent_codes
0              4      4
1              8      3
2             12      5
3             16      6
4             24      5
```

Comment: What is your desired output? If you simply want to fill the NaNs, append [`.fillna(args)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to your concatenation.

Comment: thanks @N. Wouda, edited query to answer you. I do not want to fill the NaNs, just want to simply zip the 2 dataframes together

Comment: Your example concatenates without any nans.  It might help if you show an example that *doesn't* work.

Comment: I feel like this is too simple, but may I suggest `df_A['continent_codes'] = df_B['continent_codes']`?

Comment: @DSM, yes it does! I did not include axis=1

Comment: @user308827: but you didn't include the code you were using, so we had no way of knowing that was the problem.  :-)  I thought the real problem was that your indices didn't agree.

Comment: sorry about that, I should have :) I assumed that concatenate was going to search for common values

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following code will do as you want :

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

[Source](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-with-mixed-ndims)

Output:

```
   country_codes  continent_codes
0              4                4
1              8                3
2             12                5
3             16                6
4             24                5
```

Comment: I had index error. It was fixed this way:  dfc = pd.concat([dfa.reset_index(),dfb.reset_index()],axis=1)

Answer (score 2):

From the comments:

*I feel like this is too simple, but may I suggest:*

```
df_A['continent_codes'] = df_B['continent_codes']
print(df_A)
```

Output:

```
   country_codes  continent_codes
0              4                4
1              8                3
2             12                5
3             16                6
4             24                5
```

Comment: I like this method also but it only works with 1 column.