# How to zip two pandas dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two Pandas dataframes like the ones below (sample code given [here](https://repl.it/repls/TornPastRadius)).

```
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-01  0.298399 -0.738440 -0.505438  0.324951
2000-01-02  1.300686 -0.938543 -1.850977  0.868467
```

and

```
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-03  0.328032  0.325845 -0.289175  0.393732
2000-01-04  0.091853 -1.450642 -0.544152  1.073248
```

and I would like to `zip` them so I can process their values. To clarify, I am trying to take two rows at a time — by zipping the corresponding rows together. I do not want to create a new df unless it would be more efficient that way.

---

I did the first thing that came to mind, i.e.,

```
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(df1, df2)):
    print(i, x, y)
```

and expected to get something like:

```
0 (0.298399 -0.738440 -0.505438  0.324951) (0.328032  0.325845 -0.289175  0.393732)
1 (1.300686 -0.938543 -1.850977  0.868467) (0.091853 -1.450642 -0.544152  1.073248)
```

but what I got was:

```
0 A A
1 B B
```

**How can one get the *typical* `zip` behavior when working with dataframes?**

<sub>Surprisingly, I could not find a duplicate for my question since both [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45565311/pandas-interleave-zip-two-dataframes-by-row) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332960/interweave-two-dataframes) are asking something different.</sub>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zip pandas dataframes into a new dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318141/zip-pandas-dataframes-into-a-new-dataframe)

Comment: @ITWorld I already saw this and it is not what I am trying to do (*"I do not want to create a new df..."*).

Comment: "so I can process their values" what do you plan on doing?

Comment: @coldspeed The values are then used to construct symbolic equations with `sympy`.

Comment: Okay, and you are trying to zip two rows together?

Comment: @coldspeed Is that not clear from the question? ☺

Comment: No, not exactly. Or maybe I'm just tired. Anyway, I expected to see something like "I am trying to zip the rows together" but all I see was "zip two DataFrames", and I was not sure what you were referring to when you said "typical zip behaviour".

Comment: @coldspeed Or maybe I am. Anyway, feel free to edit it to make it more clear if it is misleading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert DataFrames to numpy arrays:

```
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(df1.values, df2.values)):
    print(i, x, y)
```

Your solution return columns names, becuse is processes like:

```
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(df1.columns, df2.columns)):
    print(i, x, y)
```